# Dual Wan Load Balancing speed

Tags: router, isp, wan, internet-speed

I have a Dual WAN Linksys LRT224 and two ISPs.

If I have two 50mbps ISP configured in load balancing, will my overall speed increase above 50mbps or close to 100mbps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no

The Linksys LRT224 doesn't support WAN Bonding only Load Balancing which would not give a single TCP connect the combined total speeds.

Load balancing will split connection requests coming into it between the two lines.